# How can I tell when HTTP Headers have been sent in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

Long story short, I have an ASP.NET application I'm trying to debug and at some point, in very particular circumstances, the application will throw exceptions at a `Response.Redirect()` stating:

```
"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."
```

Which I more or less get, except that I cannot figure out *where* the headers were sent.

Is there something to look for in an ASP.NET application that will indicate that the HTTP headers have been sent?

**BONUS DIFFICULTY:** The ASP.NET app is still in .NET 1.1. The circumstances regarding the delay behind the upgrade are a really sore subject.

Comment: Response Buffering (`Response.Buffer` - you want this on) and Response Flushing (`Response.Flush()` - you don't want to do this) are two obvious candidates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`HttpApplication` has an event `PreSendRequestHeaders` which is called just when headers are writtne.  Subscribe to this and log it or add a breakpoint.

Beyond that, `HttpResponse` has a **internal** property called `HeadersWritten` (`_headersWritten` field in .NET 1.1).  Since it's internal you can't access it directly, but you can through reflection.  If this is only for internal debugging (i.e., not production code), then it's be fine to use reflection.

Check this method before/after all the page lifecylce events.  Once you know which event is writing out the headers, add more `HeadersWritten` checks to find out where they're getting written.  Through progressive narrowing of checks to this property, you'll find it.

*New info*

`HeadersWritten` property is public starting from .Net 4.5.2

Comment: This looks really good... except I forgot to mention the app is in .NET 1.1 and this looks to be a .NET 2.0+ solution.

Comment: @Schnapple, .NET 1.1 is really old.  You should always specify the version whenever you're talking about an old version.  In .NET 1.1 there was just a private field, `_headersWritten`, which you can read through reflection.

Comment: `HeadersWritten` property is public starting from .Net 4.5.2

Comment: @JakubKonecki thanks for the addition, good info. I edited my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: Kudos to u  Bro :)

Answer (score 5):

Samuel's reply just solved this problem for me (+1). I can't paste a code sample in a comment, but in the interest of helping others, here's how I used the event he suggested to add a HeadersWritten property to my IHTTPHandler:

```
protected bool HeadersWritten { get; private set; }

void ApplicationInstance_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HeadersWritten = false;
}

void ApplicationInstance_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HeadersWritten = true;
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
{
    context.ApplicationInstance.PreSendRequestHeaders += new EventHandler(ApplicationInstance_PreSendRequestHeaders);
    do_some_stuff();
}
```

In my code that would break if I mess with headers too late, I simply check the HeadersWritten property first:

```
if (!HeadersWritten)
{
    Context.Response.StatusDescription = get_custom_description(Context.Response.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that each instance of an `HttpApplication` object might serve multiple (but always sequential) requests, so you *must* reset the flag during the BeginRequest event. This also applies to an `HTTPHandler` that has the `IsReusable` property returning true. See [HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) and [IsResuable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx) in MSDN for details.

Comment: Thanks for that, Euro. To be clear, I'm adding this property and the associated code & events to my class which inherits from IHttpHandler. It was my understanding that this class should be single-use for this request, and thus totally safe from interference from other requests. If this understanding is not correct, please let me know!

Comment: One of the members of the IHttpHandler interface is a property called `IsReusable` (I misspelled it in my original comment). If your implementation is essentially `public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }`, then you're fine: ASP.NET will instantiate an object for each request and then throw it away. If you return `true`, then ASP.NET will reuse your instances for multiple requests and you are not thread-safe.

Comment: You could also just store the bool into the HttpContext.Items which maintains state for the request. This would ensure the value is only for a specific request and not global. See [Example](http://blog.richardadleta.com/2014/02/aspnet-how-to-detect-whether-headers.html).

Comment: `HeadersWritten` property is public starting from .Net 4.5.2