# ASP.NET Request Lifecycle

Tags: asp.net

say I have a folder in my web app, with an `index.html` inside it:

```
/test
/test/index.html
```

and the following `Module`

```
public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.ReleaseRequestState += context_ReleaseRequestState;
    }

    static void context_ReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = sender as HttpApplication;

        // foo
    }
}
```

If I make a request to `/test/index.html`, `context_ReleaseRequestState` fires and the response is returned, great.

If I make a request to `/test/`, `context_ReleaseRequestState` fires as above, the response is returned, but then `context_ReleaseRequestState` fires again!

The response has already been returned (and the connection closed, etc).
The `HttpContext.Response` object has the followng properties set on it:

```
HeadersWritten: true
Headers: Server=Microsoft-IIS%2f7.5
```

What is causing this second invocation?

on the `Request`the `FilePath` property for the first invocation is `/test/index.html`, and for the second its `/test/`

Is there some property on the `HttpApplication` or `HttpRequest` that I can check that identifies this 2nd request for whatever it is? The `HeadersWritten` property is internal :(

Thanks

Comment: Please see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382094/how-can-i-tell-when-http-headers-have-been-sent-in-an-asp-net-application