# ASP.NET Identify if response is flushed

Tags: asp.net, webforms, httpresponse

I want to know is there any property in Response object of ASP.NET that can tell me if response has already been flushed and no further actions can be performed on the response ?

I have a application where we add cookies to each outgoing response (through HTTP module), now if response is already flushed then cookie addition causes error.

can anyone help me out in this one.

Comment: "we add cookies to each outgoing response (through HTTP module), now if response is already flushed then cookie addition causes error." - I can't imagine how you would be ending up in that situation.

Comment: @MitchWheat: i didnt get , what you wanted to say.

Comment: I have the same problem here, I need to know if the Response had been flushed to prevent cookie error, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may need an answer to this and came here from google or else like me, here is a similar question for which a solution is given :
[How can I tell when HTTP Headers have been sent in an ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382094/how-can-i-tell-when-http-headers-have-been-sent-in-an-asp-net-application)